# jqgrid mobile scrolling issue

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

Scrolling jqgrid table in mobile( `autowidth:true, shrinkToFit:false` ) misaligns headers and data and these two re-adjust only after a moment or two.How can I make this process of scrolling smooth where header and data move together and hence don't misalign?

Comment: Which version of free jqGrid you use? Could you provide *the demo* which can be used to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @Oleg My jqgrid implementation behaves differently for different mobiles.In some it allows scrolling of data( to right ) and in others only few columns are shown rest are hidden and no scrolling is available.

Comment: **Which version of free jqGrid you use?** The version 4.13.1 contains essential performance improvement of scrolling in the case very close to what you describe. See [the issue]() for more details. Thus *it's important to know whether you use free jqGrid 4.13.1 or an early version of free jqGrid*.

Comment: @Oleg I am using 4.13.1.I have tried putting `overflow-x:scroll` to make the hidden columns appear  but it does not seem to be working.Unfortunately, I cannot provide a demo.Can you point to the general direction where problem arises so that I can try those things.

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't understand the problem. I can't help you in any way till I don't understand what you do, and how the problem looks like. The statement about hidden columns, `overflow-x:scroll` and so on shows me that I have really no idea what you do, because I don't understand how hidden columns could have any relation with the problem which you reported.